Integration testing issues with spring boot 3.3.3 hibernate 6.5.2.Final
I used spring boot 3.2.2 and I. Updated to 3.3.3.
Since I have updated, all integration test fail :
Here are my configuration :
Spring boot 3.3.3
Mockito core 5.14.2
Here is the stack trace :
14:50:42.845 [main] INFO  c.b.f.s.c.CodeRepositoryRepositoryTest - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

14:50:44.111 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.

14:50:44.494 [main] INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 381 ms. Found 14 JPA repository interfaces.

14:50:45.049 [main] INFO  o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope - BeanFactory id=105bf6e7-eb62-3ab0-9c77-142f73d4eb3f

14:50:45.673 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-2 - Starting...

14:50:45.675 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-2 - Added connection conn10: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA

14:50:45.677 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-2 - Start completed.

14:50:45.680 [main] INFO  o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]

14:50:45.690 [main] INFO  o.h.c.i.RegionFactoryInitiator - HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled

14:50:45.721 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo - No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer

14:50:45.724 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.orm.deprecation - HHH90000025: H2Dialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)

14:50:46.084 [main] ERROR o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister

14:50:46.084 [main] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister

14:50:46.085 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...

14:50:46.116 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-2 - Shutdown completed.

14:50:46.139 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger -

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

14:50:46.141 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)

              at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)

              at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)

              at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)

              at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)

              at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)

              at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)

              at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)

              at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)

              at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1463)

              at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)

              at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)

              at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)

              at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)

              at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)

              at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)

              at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)

              at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)

              at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)

              at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)

              at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378)

              at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:383)

              at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378)

              at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)

              at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)

              at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708)

              at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)

              at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)

              at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)

              at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)

              at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)

              at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)

              at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)

              at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:290)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)

              at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)

              at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:279)

              at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)

              at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)

              at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)

              at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)

              at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)

              at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)

              at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)

              at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)

              at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)

              at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)

              at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)

              at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)

              at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)

              at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)

              at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150)

              at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)

              at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)

              at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)

              at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)

              at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)

Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister

============================

              at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)

CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT

============================

              at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)

              at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366)

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)

Positive matches:

-----------------

              at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802)

              ... 87 common frames omitted

    None

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister

              at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:105)

              at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)

Negative matches:

              at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.processBootEntities(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:249)

-----------------

              at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:183)

    None

Exclusions:

-----------

    None

              at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:371)

              at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300)

Unconditional classes:

----------------------

    None

              at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457)

              at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506)

              at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75)

              at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)

              at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)

              ... 91 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type

              at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:170)

              at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:190)

              at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.load(ByteBuddyState.java:200)

              at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.loadProxy(ByteBuddyState.java:115)

              at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyHelper.buildProxy(ByteBuddyProxyHelper.java:62)

              at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyFactory.postInstantiate(ByteBuddyProxyFactory.java:65)

              at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.createProxyFactory(EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.java:305)

              at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.resolveProxyFactory(EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.java:179)

              at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.<init>(EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.java:145)

              at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.ManagedTypeRepresentationResolverStandard.resolveStrategy(ManagedTypeRepresentationResolverStandard.java:62)

              at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:539)

              at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.<init>(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:187)

              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)

              at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)

              at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)

              at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:94)

              ... 101 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call super (or default) method for public abstract void org.hibernate.engine.spi.ManagedEntity.$$_hibernate_setUseTracker(boolean)

              at net.bytebuddy.implementation.SuperMethodCall$Appender.apply(SuperMethodCall.java:133)

              at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyCode(TypeWriter.java:732)

              at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:717)

              at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:624)

              at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:6077)

              at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:2246)

              at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$UsingTypeWriter.make(DynamicType.java:4057)

              at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3741)

              at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.make(ByteBuddyState.java:243)

              at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.make(ByteBuddyState.java:232)

              at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState$1.run(ByteBuddyState.java:207)

              at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState$1.run(ByteBuddyState.java:204)

              at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.lambda$load$0(ByteBuddyState.java:217)

              at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:168)_

I noticed that spring boot 3.3.3 include hibernate core 6.5.2.Final, that may be relative to the error in the stack trace about method hibernate_setUseTracker(boolean).
I updated hibernate version to 6.4.1.Final (include in spring boot 3.2.2) and I don't have any errors, integration tests passed.
So it seems there is a breaking change in the usage of Mockito, bytebuddy and hibernate.
The method hibernate_setUseTracker(boolean) does not appear in 6.4.1.Final hibernate version
Do you have also this error by using this spring boot version ?

Some questions... Did you force the usage of Mockito 5.14.2 through dependency or overriding <mockito.version> maven property? Did you override also the managed bytebuddy version (it should be at most 1.14.19) with the latest (1.15.7)? Aso in this case it's better to do with <byte-buddy.version> property.
